# useradmin problem adding user (Call to undefined method Auth_ORM::register())

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

When I try to add a user this is the error I get:

ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Auth_ORM::register()

It does not make any sense. I added ORM and AUTH... For some reason it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are referring to the useradmin module of mixu (https://github.com/mixu/useradmin) for the Kohana php framework. 
This problem goes away if you add the module BEFORE the auth and orm modules in bootstrap.php

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a register method in Auth. You'll have to enter the details into the database using ORM. The User model hashes the password automatically.

https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/model/auth/user.php#L53